# Text file row headings to columns in excel

Tags: vba, excel, text-files

A text file with the following content:

```
userId=10101
givenname=Mark
orclmaidenname=Visser
mail=m.visser@somecompany.nl

userID=10102
givenname=Jan
orclmaidenname=Klaassen

userID=10104
givenname=Jessica
orclmaidenname=Host
mail=j.host@somecompany.nl
```

And so on.

How do I convert this txt file to an excel worksheet where the row headings from the text file will be column headers and the rows from the excel sheet are filled with the corresponding values from the text file?

The txt file has more than 1000 items, but not all items have the same row headings (for example some do not have a "mail").

This is what I have so far. It pulls "uid", "givenname", "orclmaidenname", correctly. However, adding "mail" results in an unexpected result. I think because not all items contain the row heading "mail".

```
Sub Frank()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Name current file
    MyMacroFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'   Prompt for file
    MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*")
    If MyFile = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

'   Open file
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=MyFile, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 2)
'   Name text file
    MyTextFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'   Find cell with "uid", "givenname", "orclmaidenname"
    Do
        Windows(MyTextFile).Activate
'       Exit loop if can't find any matches
        On Error GoTo Err_Fix
            Cells.Find(What:="uid=", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
        :=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate
            Cells.Find(What:="givenname=", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
        :=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate
            Cells.Find(What:="orclmaidenname=", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
        :=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate
        On Error GoTo 0
'   Exit loop if starting search over form top
        If ActiveCell.Row <= MyRow Then
            Exit Do
        End If
'   Get specific characters of selected rows
        MyValue = Right(ActiveCell.Value, 6)
        MyValue2 = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 10)
        MyValue3 = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 15)
        MyRow = ActiveCell.Row
'   Paste value in spreadsheet with macro in columns A, B and C
        Windows(MyMacroFile).Activate
        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = MyValue
        Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = MyValue2
        Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = MyValue3
    Loop

Err_Fix:
    Windows(MyTextFile).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Any insight?

Comment: What was that "unexpected result"?

Comment: Basically, it mixed the whole spreadsheet up. Columns contained values from different rows that didn't match the original.

Comment: Does this really work okay? It appears as though it just selects a cell with `orclmaidenname=` and then populates your other worksheet with parts of its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this doesn't match your code but I've never read text files using VBA so I was kind of teaching myself here. This code reads the file `test.txt`, which I copied from the text you provided. As long as the first three fields are populated you shouldn't run into any errors, but a missing `mail` field is not a problem. The code works by taking anything after the `=` for every row after the first row and moving to a new row after the blank line.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim fname As String
    Dim txt As String
    Dim rowID As Long
    Dim colID As Long
    Dim pos As Integer

    fname = "H:\test.txt"
    Open fname For Input As #1

    rowID = 1
    colID = 1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, txt
        If rowID = 1 And txt <> "" Then
            pos = InStr(1, txt, "=")
            Cells(rowID, colID).Value = Left(txt, pos - 1) 'Populate the field names
            Cells(rowID + 1, colID).Value = Right(txt, Len(txt) - pos) 'Populate the second row (first row of data) 
            colID = colID + 1
        ElseIf txt = "" Then
            If rowID = 1 Then rowID = rowID + 1 'Increase the rowID by 1 since we have already populated the first row of data.
            colID = 1     'Set the colID back to 1 for the new row
            rowID = rowID + 1   'Move to a new row
        Else
            pos = InStr(1, txt, "=")
            Cells(rowID, colID).Value = Right(txt, Len(txt) - pos)  'Print out everything after the "=" to the cell
            colID = colID + 1    'Move to new column
        End If
    Loop

    Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank! It appears to be working. Only thing is if an item is missing in the txt file, for example "mail=", the next value is displayed in the "mail" column. Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: @Grote You could change the `if-statements` to do something like: If everything left of the `=` in the `txt` variable is `userID` then `colID = 1` and then move on like that.